# Enable zip on PHP 5.1.6 without recompile

Tags: php, redhat, centos5

I've got a CentOS / Red Hat 5.5 box running the current PHP 5.1.6 package.  A user is getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in /var/www/html/<filename.php> on line 225
```

Based on some reading it looks like PHP wants to have had the --enable-zip flag at compile time, however we are running the packaged version for RedHat / Cent.  I'm not excited about compiling PHP from source just to enable this option; is there a way to enable the zip functions without resorting to a custom compile?

Other info... in php.ini I  have:

```
zlib.output_compression = On
; zlib.output_handler =
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the zlib-devel package installed when you install the PHP package, it will count as if the enable-zip flag is set.

`yum install zlib-devel && yum install php`

You might need to uninstall php if the same version in the repos is installed.

Answer (score 1):

ZipArchive class come with PHP 5.2, you have php 5.1.x in your server

solutions:

- That your user check their software, if is custom made, that use the zip_* functions instead the ZipArchive class, if not, that try to search a version that support PHP 5.1.x.
- Upgrade your php in your CentOS server to 5.2, you can use IUS Community repo http://iuscommunity.org/, remi repo http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en CentAltRU, http://centos.alt.ru for this (and test that your other php sofware dont get affected)